# How to get a key from a dict python

Tags: python

I need to accumulate the count of each of the 26 letters within a body of text into a dictionary. When the user types a letter, I need to display the frequency of that letter within the text. How shall I go about this?

This is my code so far:

```
import urllib2
import numpy as py
import matplotlib

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://students.healthinformaticshub.ca/jane-austen-sense-n-sensibility.txt')

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

# initialize the dict we will use to store our
# counts for the individual vowels:
alphabet_counts = {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 0, 'h': 0,\
'i': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 0, 'n': 0, 'o': 0, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 0, 's': 0,\
't': 0, 'u': 0, 'v': 0, 'w': 0, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}

total_letter_count = 0

# loop thru line by line:
for line in response:
    line = line.lower()

    for ch in line:
        if ch in alphabet:
            alphabet_counts[ch] += 1
            total_letter_count += 1


print('# of a\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['a']))
print('# of b\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['b']))
print('# of c\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['c']))
print('# of d\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['d']))
print('# of e\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['e']))
print('# of f\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['f']))
print('# of g\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['g']))
print('# of h\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['h']))
print('# of i\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['i']))
print('# of j\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['j']))
print('# of k\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['k']))
print('# of l\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['l']))
print('# of m\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['m']))
print('# of n\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['n']))
print('# of o\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['o']))
print('# of p\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['p']))
print('# of q\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['q']))
print('# of r\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['r']))
print('# of s\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['s']))
print('# of t\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['t']))
print('# of u\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['u']))
print('# of v\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['v']))
print('# of w\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['w']))
print('# of x\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['x']))
print('# of y\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['y']))
print('# of z\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts['z']))


resp = '''
1.) Find probability of a particular letter of the alphabet 
2.) Show the barplot representing these probabilities for the entire alphabet
3.) Save that barplot as a png file
4.) Quit'''
```

Comment: Take a look at the class [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). You should be able to use it to replace the entire inner loop, then discard all the keys not in the dictionary. Alternatively, just filter out the non-letter characters from the line when you pass it in to the counter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you really want, and since you are just learning. I'll provide you with a hint rather than the answer. A `dict` object has a method called `items` and `iteritems`. To get both keys and values. To compute the probability of getting a given character you can use iteritems:

```
char_probabilities = dict()
for character, count in alphabet_counts.iteritems():
    # compute probability given the
    # frequency of character her you can use the 
    # sum builtin and values method on the dict
    char_probabilities[character] = [YOU DO SOME WORK]
```

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up some of your code and I also added an example on how to use `raw_input` (because you're using Python 2.7 based on your use of urllib2):

```
import urllib2
import numpy as py
import matplotlib

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://students.healthinformaticshub.ca/jane-austen-sense-n-sensibility.txt')

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

# initialize the dict we will use to store our
# counts for the individual vowels:
alphabet_counts = {letter: 0 for letter in alphabet}

total_letter_count = 0

# loop thru line by line:
for line in response:
    line = line.lower()

    for ch in line:
        if ch in alphabet:
            alphabet_counts[ch] += 1
            total_letter_count += 1

for letter in alphabet_counts:
    print('# of ' + letter + '\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts[letter]))

letter = raw_input("Enter a character: ")
print('# of ' + letter + '\'s: ' + str(alphabet_counts[letter]))

resp = '''
1.) Find probability of a particular letter of the alphabet 
2.) Show the barplot representing these probabilities for the entire alphabet
3.) Save that barplot as a png file
4.) Quit'''
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a textbook use of the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class:

```
import collections, urllib2, contextlib

url = 'http://students.healthinformaticshub.ca/jane-austen-sense-n-sensibility.txt'
alphabet_counts = collections.Counter()
with contextlib.closing(urllib2.urlopen(url)) as response:
    for line in response:
        alphabet_counts.update(x for x in line.lower() if x.isalpha())
```

The counter is a `dict` subclass that will behave just like your original `alphabet_counts`, but with much less effort on your part. Keep in mind that you probably want to close the input stream, which is why I am using the `with` block.

To get the frequencies, you need to know the sum of the counter values:

```
total_letters = sum(alphabet_counts.values())
frequencies = {letter: float(count) / total_letters for count, letter in alphabet_counts.iteritems()}
```